# The SNES emulator ZSNES was removed when updating to Kubuntu 23.10 (mantic)

Tags: emulation, zsnes

The SNES emulator ZSNES was removed when updating to Kubuntu 23.10 (mantic).

[A package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zsnes) shows that ZSNES is available only up to 23.04 (lunar).

Why was it removed and where can I find it or an alternative for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `zsnes` was maintained by Debian and the maintainer decided to remove it because [the development of ZSNES has ceased in 2007](https://zsnes.com/index.php?page=news).

The issue is discussed in two Debian bug reports:

- [#1039564 zsnes: is limited to the i386 architecture](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1039564)
- [#1039568 RM: zsnes -- ROM; i386-only, abandoned upstream, alternatives exist](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1039568)

The maintainer suggests several alternatives (which I did not test):

- [ares](https://packages.ubuntu.com/ares)
- [higan](https://packages.ubuntu.com/higan)
- [mednafen](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mednafen)
- [libretro-bsnes-mercury](https://packages.ubuntu.com/libretro-bsnes-mercury) with a frontend like [retroarch](https://packages.ubuntu.com/retroarch)

If you don't want to look into alternatives yet, you can still download the [latest package for zsnes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsnes/+bug/695507/+attachment/5710540/+files/zsnes_1.510+bz2-10.2_i386.deb) and install with `sudo dpkg -i zsnes_1.510+bz2-10.2_i386.deb`. It works for me under Kubuntu 23.10 (mantic). But at some point the package will break and it will not be fixed, so use at your own risk. Only the architecture i386 is offered, more recent CPU architectures will not be supported.